# How do I close a windows program in BASH

Tags: windows, command-line, bash

I use X64-based Win10. Recently, I started to use git, so I am switching the console to bash/mingw64. But I don't quite understand the way bash behaves.

I tried to kill a program, say notepad, via command line. Supposedly,

```
TASKKILL /IM notepad.exe
```

works.

I check the help documentation of `taskkill` in Bash. This line is in fact one of the EXAMPLES.

However, I got this error

```
$ TASKKILL /IM notepad.exe 

ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'C:/Program Files/Git/IM'.
```

Also, `TASKKILL /PID <number>` doesn't work either, and same error comes out.

May someone explain what might go wrong?

P.S. This can be solved by type `cmd`, which then runs the command in `cmd` and works. But it is kind of slow, and arrows don't work(annoying).

Comment: Does it work if you double the slash (`TASKKILL //IM notepad.exe`)?

Comment: Tried. I also used > help taskkill to look for info about taskkill, and it signaled the error "bash: help: no help topics match `taskkill'.  Try `help help' or `man -k taskkill' or `info taskkill'."  But if I use >taskkill /?, it brings out the help documentation; meanwhile >help time (for example) works.

Comment: What happens if you try running these five commands?  `which taskkill` ; `type taskkill` ; `echo ${WINDIR}` ; `/windows/system32/taskkill.exe /IM notepad.exe` ; `CMD /C TaskKill /IM notepad.exe`

Comment: which taskkill----/c/windows/system32/taskkill   /// type taskkill---
taskkill is hashed (/c/windows/system32/taskkill) //// echo ${WINDIR}---
C:\WINDOWS /// /windows/system32/taskkill.exe /IM notepad.exe----
bash: /windows/system32/taskkill.exe: No such file or directory/// CMD /C TaskKill /IM notepad.exe----
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: forgot to mention: if I use `cmd //c taskkill //im notepad.exe` ; then it works. I am sorry for the last comment; I was in a hurry and forgot to use formatting.

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution use `tskill` instead of taskkill

Use `$ tskill notepad`

Comment: Unfortunately; this is what I get>bash: tskill: command not found

Comment: How do you start notepad ? i do `start notepad` to open notepad and to close `tskill notepad` . make sure you have added git bash PATH in your Environmental variable path

Comment: `start`  is not a problem. That's where I don't understand: for some command it works fine; others, not so fine. The one in my enviroment is **C:\MinGW\bin**, is it correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Add this path and try again `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`

Comment: added it, restarted it, but doesn't work. But I tried this command in `cmd`  directly, which says `tskill` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: uninstall MinGW, use git bash go to git-scm.com. And use it only for Git.